# class anonymous class derived from OnSeekBarChangeListener

Tags: java, android

I don't know how to fix the error that is marked with the red line on SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener(). When I hover on the error it says this.

*class anonymous class derived from OnSeekBarChangeListener Class must either be declared abstract or implement abstract method onProgessChanged(SeekBar, int, boolean) in OnSeekBarChangeListener*

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.SeekBar;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private MediaPlayer song;
    boolean playing=false;
    int length;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        song = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.portland);
        SeekBar volume=(SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.seekBar);

        volume.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener(){

            @Override
            public void onProgessChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser){

                Log.i("SeekBar value", Integer.toString(progress));

            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }


        });

    }
```

Comment: what is your current error??

Comment: You're missing the second `r` in `onProgressChanged`.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the **r** in your onProg**r**essChanged call back.

write this

```
  @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser){

            Log.i("SeekBar value", Integer.toString(progress));

        }
```

Instead of this

```
  @Override
        public void onProgessChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser){

            Log.i("SeekBar value", Integer.toString(progress));

        }
```

Your error will be resolved